# online Vickrey auction using remote coin flip

Tags: oblivious-transfer

Is there any published work on implementing a online auction, which uses "remote coin flip" to prevent auctioneer cheating when choosing winner and bid value?
Is there any possible way to use remote coin flip for a such scenario?

Note: in a [Vickrey auction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickrey_auction), bidders submit written bids without knowing the bid of the other people in the auction; the highest bidder wins but the price paid is the second-highest bid.